# Clojurescript - map from list of subvecs

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm trying to create a map from a list of 2-element `Subvec`s.

This works fine in Clojure:

```
(into {} (list (subvec [1 2 3] 1)))
>> {2 3}
```

But fails in ClojureScript, with the following error:

```
No protocol method IMapEntry.-key defined for type number: 2
```

Replacing `(subvec [1 2 3] 1)` with `[2 3]` makes it work in both languages.

I'm new to ClojureScript, and can't find where this behaviour is documented. Is this a bug? And how would you suggest going around it efficiently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's an omission. Subvectors should be indistinguishable from ordinary vectors, and therefore [Subvec](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/797e247fbef676544060a57da995f058db061f37/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5511) should have an implementation of IMapEntry added to it, like [the one in PersistentVector](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/797e247fbef676544060a57da995f058db061f37/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L5288-L5292).

Comment: Thanks! I added an implementation using `extend-type`, which fixed my problem.